# Laravel - retorno errado de ultimo elemento do banco dentro de um loop

Tags: mysql, laravel-5.4

Quando são inseridos registros dentro de um `loop` e é feito um `select` para pegar o ultimo registro baseado em uma condicional, depois da **quinta** interação ele não pega mais o ultimo registro e fica pegando sempre o quinto.

Estou usando `Laravel` com o banco `MySQL` e possuo uma tabela com os campos:

- id
- codigo
- cliente_id
- data
- sequencial_ano

O sequencial ano será usado para montar um código baseado no ano e na sequencia como por exemplo:

- FC124/2018
- FC125/2018
- FC1/2019
- FC2/2019
- FC3/2019

O meu algoritmo segue os seguintes passos:

1. Grava um novo registro com o cliente_id e a data. (o id é autonumeração)
2. Pega o max de sequencial_ano de um determinado ano
3. Soma +1
4. Monta um código baseado nesses valores. Ex. Se o sequencial_ano máximo de 2019 for 3 então ele irá gerar o código FC4/2019
5. Faz o update do codigo e sequencial_ano no registro.

O código abaixo é do método que gera o novo código e atualiza no registro. A variável **$insert** já possui o **obj** com o registro atual que foi inserido para poder atualizar.

Esse método é chamado dentro de um loop que insere um registro e chama o método **gerarCodigo()** passando o registro inserido.

```
public function gerarCodigo($insert)
{

     $ultimoNumeroAno = \App\Ficha::where(
       DB::Raw('year(data)'), date('Y')
     )->max('sequencial_ano');

     $numero_ano = $ultimoNumeroAno + 1;

     $codigo = 'FC'.($numero_ano).'/'.date('Y');

     $insert->update(
        ['codigo' => $codigo, 
         'sequencial_ano' => $numero_ano
        ]
     );
```

Até a quinta interação o `sequencial_ano` é pego corretamente, mas depois sempre fica pegando o **5** repetidamente e são feita em média um total repetições.

Alguém sabe o motivo disso? Existe alguma forma melhor de pegar o ultimo `sequencial_ano` de um ano?

Observação: também já tentei usar com `order_by('id', 'desc')->first()` *e deu na mesma*

Comment: poderia ser gravado somente o número sequencia do ano vai facilitar na hora de somar + 1 e ai se for ter que mostrar FC grava em um campo ou só mostre quando for exibir

Comment: Obrigado, mas descobri que estava usando o ano atual mesmo quando a ficha gerada tinha uma data de outro ano. Postei uma resposta explicando tudo.

Answer (score 0):

Acabei de descobrir o problema.

Nesse trecho **DB::Raw('year(data)'), date('Y'))** estou usando a função date() do php para pegar a data atual. Mas o correto seria pegar a data do registro atual. Uma particularidade que havia esquecido de mencionar é que cada registro é um mês.

Ou seja, quando virou o ano para 2020 ele a condição no where ficou travada em 2019 e com isso pegava sempre o mesmo sequencial.

Passei a pegar o ano desta forma:

```
$ano = date('Y', strtotime($insert->data));
```

E nas partes onde usava **data('Y')**, passei a usar a variavel **$ano**

```
where(DB::Raw('year(data)'), $ano)

$codigo = 'FC'.($numero_ano).'/'.$ano;
```

Eu pensava que o problema era executar varias interações de BD em um loop, mas na verdade foi apenas um erro de lógica.